# Pausing main process until spawned process begins execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I keep the main process from continuing until a spawned process has begun its execution?

Suppose I had the following simple example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo():
    print ("In 'foo'")
    while True:
        pass

def bar():
    print ("In 'bar'")
    count = 0
    while count < 5001:
        count += 1

def main():
    print ("In 'main'")
    p = mp.Process(target = foo, args = ())
    p.start()
    # stop here until 'foo()' prints
    bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As I understand it, when a `Process.start()` occurs, the process has to "reimport" everything from `__main__`, and because of this, in my program there is a delay from when `foo()` would begin, yet `__main__` continues while the new process is starting up.

The only working method I have is using a `multiprocessing.Pipe()`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(s):
    print ("In 'foo'")
    s.close()
    while True:
        pass

def bar():
    print ("In 'bar'")
    count = 0
    while count < 5001:
        count += 1

def main():
    print ("In 'main'")
    r, s = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target = foo, args = (s,))
    p.start()
    while not s.closed:
        pass
    bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But this seems clunky since I dont even use the `Pipe()` for what it is meant for. Another method I thought would work was to use a `multiprocessing.Lock()`, but because of the "reimport" delay, the target method does acquire the lock before `bar()` is executed on `__main__`.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event). You can make you main process wait for the event to be set before continuing. And your child process will set the event when it start in your target function.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def foo(process_started):
    print ("In 'foo'")
    time.sleep(5)  # Sleep to show that the main process is waiting for the event
    process_started.set()
    while True:
        pass

def bar():
    print ("In 'bar'")
    count = 0
    while count < 5001:
        count += 1

def main():
    print ("In 'main'")
    process_started = mp.Event()
    p = mp.Process(target = foo, args = (process_started,))
    p.start()
    process_started.wait()  # Wait for the Event to be set
    bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I don't know, it should work.

Comment: On a non-forking system like windows, the child process would create a new `process_started`. Setting it would not be seen in the parent. It should be created in `main` and passed to the child.

Comment: @tdelaney Yep, that's it. Now it works. That should be added to the answer.

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry I only tested in linux system. Didn't know that event in windows behaved differently. I thought that Event object created with the multiprocessing module are shared between process.

Comment: As mentioned, the [`spawn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) method is defaulted on Windows which creates an entirely new interpreter process. Further documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) on the execution of `spawn`.

Comment: This however, was a clean solution when edited for Windows.

Comment: There is no need for the `time.sleep()` call.

Comment: Yes, their is no need for the sleep, it was just for to show that the main process was waiting.